# clean dataset nulls, etc cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64] Tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following function

```
def clean_dataset(df):
    assert isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame), "df needs to be a pd.DataFrame"
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    indices_to_keep = ~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)
    return df[indices_to_keep].astype(np.float64)
```

However when I try to clean the dataframe;

```
#def main():
df = load_data()
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df.head(5)
clean_dataset(df)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64]
```

Comment: You're trying convert a datetime column into float. Do you see why that's a problem?

Comment: yes, how can I avoid to run this on date columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to filter out the numeric columns and convert only them to floats. In that case I'd change the last line in `clean_dataset` from

```
return df[indices_to_keep].astype(np.float64)
```

to

```
return df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).loc[indices_to_keep].astype(np.float64)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem in the past. The solution is to convert to string first:

```
return df[indices_to_keep].astype(str).astype(np.float64)
```